# How to click on <input> type button C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to click on by .css/by `classname` but unfortunately, it didn't work...

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="save" class="pp-btn pp-btn-primary w-70 save-item-description" data-disable-with="saving...">
  <a class="pp-btn pp-btn-danger w-70" data-disable-with="..." data-target="#item-ebay_details" data-remote="true" href="/items/468056.html?partial=ebay_details">cancel</a>
</div>
```

I need to `Click()` on  and it would be best to track it by class name...

Comment: What selector did you use?

Comment: Sorry I just started with selenium on C# so Im kinda new. Right now Im just trying to click on buttons with simple ```IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();```

Comment: Did you use `FindElement(<selector>).Click();`?

Comment: Yes I tried a couple of them. By.ClassName, By.XPath altho I think that my Xpath selector might have been poorly written.

Comment: Try `Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[class*='save-item-description']"));`

Comment: unforunately it doesnt work.. I get an exception

Comment: What exception?

Comment: [img]https://imgur.com/h5mNNyS

Comment: I don't see exception type in provided screenshot

Comment: It is not a complete 'exception'.

Comment: I dont really know how much can I show you it just says that it didint found selector type text

Comment: +  $exception {"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"xpath\",\"selector\":\"//input[@class='submit']\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)"} OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException

Comment: Edit your question and post the different code options you tried and the result of each. If there was an error message/exception, post that also. Don't post screenshots of errors or code, etc.

Comment: @TomasŠlepikas _...tried to click..._ on which element? **save** button or **cancel** element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xpath selector to find by class name:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(//input[@class='submit']);
```

Remember, you element might not be yet ready/present/clickable at the point of getting reference to it, that's why you need to either use IMPLICIT or EXPLICIT wait (it is very well documented, search for it)

You can wait for element to be clickable this way:

```
new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.XPath(//input[@class='submit']))));
```

Comment: Elaborate on 'does not work' what exactly happens, element not found exception? You should post some of your code in your question.

Comment: +  $exception {"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"xpath\",\"selector\":\"//input[@class='submit']\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)"} OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException

Comment: @TomasŠlepikas your element might be in `iframe`. Do you know how to verify that?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: "+  $exception {"Timed out after 20 seconds"} OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException
"

Comment: Open inspection tools in your browser (ex. Chrome) open website you are trying to automate, make sure you can see element you are trying to locate, in inspect tools, try to search by xpath used in the code: //input[@class='submit'] does it find it?

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you alot. Another question is if I need to read/edit a text box inside this "iframe" do I need to use the same webdriverwait?

Comment: If an element exists in an iframe, use driver.SwitchTo().Frame("nameOfIFrame") to switch the focus of the webdriver to the iframe. Afterwards, you can use the driver.FindElement again. If you don't know the name of the iframe, you can use the index as well, i.e. driver.SwitchTo().Frame(1).

To switch back to the normal frame, use driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent().